# Regression books for business people

Tags: regression, references

I am a student of MBA-Business Intelligence and Data Analytics. I would like to know names of some good books on regression analysis written from the perspective of making business decisions.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Pawan. There have been many questions here asking for recommendations for books, you can search the [tag:books] tag for some different versions of this common question. To make your question distinct, I edited the text to focus it more explicitly on books specific to *making business decisions*; make sure the question is still acceptable to you.

Answer (score 1):

I have taught statistics to business majors (undergraduates and MBAs) at Cal State Fullerton and USC at Irvine.  I can recommend the business statistics books that i have used.  These books include general hypothesis testing and time series in addition to regression but they are all well written use business applications and give excellent coverage to regression.  As an MBA student you should be interested in these other aspects of statistics related to business anyway.  Here is my list:

1. Not a book that I used because it is more recent but still excellent:

   [Business Statistics: A First Course](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321426584)
2. Also not one that i used but David Moore is an excellent writer of introductory statistics books:

   [The Practice of Business Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/142922150X)
3. This is the book I used (an earlier edition):

   [The Practice of Business Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032164011X)
4. I know Jay Devore very well.  He is an excellent writer:

   [Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538733527)
5. I know Steve Book very well and highly recommend this book:

   [Statistical Analysis: Resolving Decision Problems in Business and Management](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0673160025)

Comment: Thank You for valuable answer. I am also looking for a business analytics project. Can you advise me where can I search for it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can be much help with that.

Answer (score 0):

A good book on regression for Execs/Managers is [Wolfgang Jank's Business Analytics for Managers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461404053).

He covers how to interpret and improve regression models in the context of business decisions, as well as using nonparametric (nonlinear) regression for predictive modeling.

Comment: Thank You for valuable answer. I am also looking for a business analytics project. Can you advise me where can I search for it?